# Is there a way to set the output format in Octave to a given number of significant digits?

Tags: format, octave

In Octave, `format short g` sets the numeric output format in the command window to 5 significant digits, and `format long g` to 15 digits. Is there a way to set it to a different number of digits different from 5 or 15? I know how to use `num2str`, `mat2str`... but I prefer it to be a default output format.

I don't think it is possible, but I am asking just in case (it would be quite useful for my use case).

Comment: You'd probably need to change the default files for `format`, if that's possible at all (they could be encrypted). Alternatively, it might be possible to create your own class and overwrite the `disp()` call (which is also the default formatting IIRC).

Comment: By the way, please read the tag descriptions of [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave]. This question is not about the similarities or differences, thus please use only **one** (I presume Octave) tag. Otherwise, solutions need to be constrained to functioning in both languages, something which might be difficult in this specific case.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, @kol's answer works great in Octave but not Matlab, so removing the Matlab keyword is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need the `output_precision` function. For example, if you want to have 7 digits in the command window, type this:

```
output_precision(7)
```